# Camera Preview in Android

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I develop one application based on Camera. It runs fine but there is one problem with Camera and Sony Xperia Sola OS with Android 4.0.

The problem is following:

When I start camera from my application camera preview is display half screen with Sony Xperia Sola device and on any other device HTC, Samsung it work nice in full Screen.

For Camera Preview I used `SurfaceView` class. and in the `SurfaceChanged()` method i use following code

```
Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
    {

        System.out.println("Preview Height : " + h);
        System.out.println("Preview Width  : " + w);

        parameters.setPreviewSize(h, w);                           
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }
```

Please help me find a solution.

Comment: My solution for this can be found on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428797/camera-camera-preview-is-not-proper-after-setdisplayorientation-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428797/camera-camera-preview-is-not-proper-after-setdisplayorientation-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as to what the height and width printouts provide when you run your app. I implemented a simple SurfaceView class and used your code. The width and height reported through logcat was

> I/System.out( 4706): Preview Width : 480
>
> I/System.out( 4706): Preview Height : 744

which is pretty consistent with how large an area the SurfaceView spans.

The Panel code I used for this:

```
public class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private Camera  mCamera;
    private Context mContext;

    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(getHolder());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)    {
        Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        Display display = ((WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(android.content.Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {

            System.out.println("Preview Width : " + width);
            System.out.println("Preview Height  : " + height);

            parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

}
```

Please provide some more details and I'll try and investigate further if necessary.

I'm running on an Xperia Sola with 4.0.4. If you could provide me the build number of your device this can be helpful as well.

Comment: I have brought it up with internal staff and awaiting a response.

Comment: I have come in contact with someone who should be able to assist and/or comment on this throughout the day. I will return with the results.

Comment: We are still working out details of the root to the issue. There has been some progress but nothing definite yet. I will return with more information during the week.

Answer (score 0):

We experience the same problem here, I used your code above to to see how it works, and it looks like the rotation center is displaced so when rotated 90 degrees to portrait it's just shows about 10-20% of the View.

It seems like it is the:

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

which causes the problem.

This is reproducable on:

- Sony Xperia ST25i, with Android version 4.0.4 (build: 6.1.1.B.1.54)
- Sony Xperia Solo MT27i, with Android 4.0.4 (build: 6.1.1.B.1.54)

Here is the Camera Parameters if they contains any information:

```
01-22 16:04:01.015: D/CameraTest(1336): Haz camera: true
01-22 16:04:01.095: D/TextLayoutCache(1336): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
01-22 16:04:01.425: D/libEGL(1336): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
01-22 16:04:01.505: D/libEGL(1336): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-22 16:04:01.535: D/libEGL(1336): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-22 16:04:01.545: D/libEGL(1336): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-22 16:04:01.725: D/OpenGLRenderer(1336): Enabling debug mode 0
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): preferred-preview-size-for-video=864x480
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): zoom=0
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): recording-hint=false
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): max-num-detected-faces-hw=5
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): zoom-supported=true
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): whitebalance=auto
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): scene-mode=auto
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): jpeg-quality=85
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): preview-format-values=yuv420sp,yuv420p
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): jpeg-thumbnail-quality=100
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): preview-format=yuv420sp
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): video-size-values=1280x720,864x480,720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): preview-size=640x480
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): focal-length=3.5
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): flash-mode-values=off,auto,on,red-eye,torch
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): preview-frame-rate-values=15,30
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): max-num-metering-areas=0
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): preview-frame-rate=30
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): focus-mode-values=auto,infinity,macro,fixed,continuous-picture,continuous-video
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): jpeg-thumbnail-width=160
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): video-size=1280x720
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): scene-mode-values=auto,portrait,landscape,night,night-portrait,beach,snow,sports,party,barcode
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): preview-fps-range-values=(1000,15000),(1000,30000)
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=160x120,0x0
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): zoom-ratios=100,107,115,123,132,141,152,162,174,187,200,214,230,246,264,283,303,325,348,373,400,429,459,492,528,566,606,650,696,746,800
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): preview-size-values=864x480,720x480,640x480,480x320,352x288,320x240,176x144
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): picture-size-values=2592x1944,2560x1440,1632x1224,1920x1080,640x480,480x320,320x240
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): preview-fps-range=1000,30000
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): auto-whitebalance-lock=false
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): min-exposure-compensation=-6
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): antibanding=auto
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): max-num-focus-areas=1
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): vertical-view-angle=360
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): horizontal-view-angle=360
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): video-stabilization-supported=false
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): jpeg-thumbnail-height=120
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): smooth-zoom-supported=true
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): focus-mode=macro
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): auto-whitebalance-lock-supported=true
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): video-frame-format=yuv420mb
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): max-num-detected-faces-sw=5
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): picture-format-values=jpeg
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): max-exposure-compensation=6
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): focus-areas=(0,0,0,0,0)
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): video-snapshot-supported=false
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): exposure-compensation=0
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): exposure-compensation-step=0.333333
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): flash-mode=off
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): auto-exposure-lock=false
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): effect-values=none,mono,negative,solarize,sepia,posterize
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): picture-size=2592x1944
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): max-zoom=30
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): effect=none
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): whitebalance-values=auto,incandescent,fluorescent,daylight,cloudy-daylight
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): picture-format=jpeg
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): focus-distances=Infinity,Infinity,Infinity
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): auto-exposure-lock-supported=true
01-22 16:04:02.987: D/CameraTest(1336): antibanding-values=auto,50hz,60hz,off
01-22 16:04:03.037: D/CameraTest(1336): Rotation : 0
01-22 16:04:03.037: D/CameraTest(1336): Preview Width : 480
01-22 16:04:03.037: D/CameraTest(1336): Preview Height  : 744
01-22 16:04:03.057: D/CameraTest(1336): Supported FPS  : [[1000, 15000], [1000, 30000]]
```

Comment: Just tried the Xperia Function Tester and it has the same problem:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonymobile.androidapp.functiontester

When making a screenshot with power + volume down it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified that the issue is related to the camera software.

Unfortunately there is no workaround available.

The only solution will be a future firmware update that includes a fix for the camera issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case with Sony Experia LT22I, when I rotate the screen with

> mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

just show about 10-20% of the view. Finally I found a solution (a patch) for this phone. Only whit change the margin Top (I don't know why) of the view this works well, like this:

```
String model = (Build.MANUFACTURER+Build.MODEL).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
if (model.equals(Constants.MODEL_EXCEPTION)) {
    final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lpt =(MarginLayoutParams)       
    surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
    lpt.setMargins(0,-150,0,0);
    surfaceView.setLayoutParams(lpt);
}
```