# Camera camera preview is not Proper after setdisplayorientation in android

Tags: android, android-camera

i m trying to implement camera in my app but i found that the orientation preview is all time in landscape but my app is in portrait so i need it in to portrait mode i found some solutions about that like

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

its working good with Galaxy tab2 and htc but when i test it in sony xperia sola it display strange hear i add image screen of it

[image]

u can see that the preview of camera its display of **right side of screen only**

but when i take picture from this app it display ok. i don't no what is the problem 
can anyone help me in this .

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @seriakillaz the problem is remain, so i use built in camera app for tacking picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to force the surface size (and position) - I followed this path to compensate a similar bug in 2.2 version of Samsung Galaxy S. The bug was fixed when the device upgraded to 2.3.

Comment: so the problem is my device OS ..?(it's 4.0.4)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this is not a feature of OS version _per se_. Camera is vendor- and model-specific. But sw upgrade may fix the problem.

Comment: +1 thanks for reply, but sony dos not provide any update for my device (this is the latest) so i m trying to re install the 4.0.4 i hope it sole my problem.ones again thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the following code:

```
class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    [...]

    public void show(){
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        if (!showing) {
            showing=true;
            try {
                mCamera = Camera.open();
                aspectRatio();

                try {
                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.text_camera_open_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void aspectRatio(){
        if (!aspect_radio_corrected){
            aspect_radio_corrected=true;
            Display default_disp=((Activity)getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            Camera.Size optimalPreviewSize=parameters.getPreviewSize();

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams l_params=(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)getLayoutParams();
            float ratio = (float) optimalPreviewSize.height / optimalPreviewSize.width;
            l_params.width=default_disp.getWidth();
            l_params.height=Math.round(l_params.width / ratio);
            setLayoutParams(l_params);
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    [...]
}
```

And on the layout file I have:

```
<com.socialcoaster.utils.CameraPreview
    android:id="@+id/cameraView"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Seems that this is a bug related with the aspect ratio of the current preview size setup on camera and the surfaceView area to show it. You can see that by simply changing the values of `aspectRatio()` to some fixed values like `100`.